# Linux Mint LiveUSB freezes after 30 seconds (Cinnamon)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, system-installation, dual-boot, live-usb

I am trying to dual boot Linux Mint with an already installed Windows 10 using LiveUSB.

However, each time on booting up from the LiveUSB, the Mint screen (desktop of live usb) freezes up even if it is left untouched. Only the mouse works and can be moved around.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330S. No dedicated GPU (have tried nomodeset, does not work). Secure boot is off. Installation in UEFI. Checksum of ISO is ok. 
Same thing happens in compatibility mode.

How to solve this? I had a number of issues during installation of Ubuntu as well on a different HP PC. It worked ultimately (the Radeon GPU was messing it up).

I'm quite tired of Ubuntu based systems' installation problems. Please also suggest an alternative Linux distribution which is smoother. I intend to set up a Kali VM on the Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu and Mint both tend to have very smooth installation processes (I also have a Radeon GPU). The issue is not them. When you say "the mint screen" you mean the boot menu for the live-cd? Or the splash screen shown during booting? or the desktop of the live cd?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Desktop of the live CD. I can even start the installation process, if done within 30 seconds. However, after around 30 seconds, the desktop is still there but all processes freeze.

Comment: Hmm, that leaves a lot of possibilities. The first thing I would check is running the memory test from the boot menu overnight. Let it make at least two full passes. I would also run a basic SMART check on any HDD installed in the system. You also might try re-burning the live-cd at significantly lower speed than the max your burner can handle... just to ensure the integrity of the burned data is as high as possible.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Thanks for your suggestions. Before I try those - I tried elementary OS and it works absolutely fine. No glitches, installation is also successful. Does this input help in narrowing down what might be going wrong with Mint?

Comment: Hmm. Not really. I mean it reduces the likelihood that it's the things I suggested... but those are still the most likely problems in my mind. It's entirely possible for different OSes or even different distros of the same OS to just happen to not trigger the specific conditions that manifest the problem... but the problem is still there. If we could see what dmesg said right before the lockup... it could also be a failure to initialize hardware correctly (a flaky kernel module). Even though Elementary is Ubuntu based, the devs might have selected different sets of modules for their live-cds.

Comment: Really there are just so many things it could be. A faster way to test memory might be to take out all but one ram stick and, if it still does it, try with one *other* ram stick. If it still does it then we can be mostly sure it's not a memory issue.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Got it. Great points. Will update on the status